# Setting a home page tab on a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress theme that does not uses a custom home page, so in when installing the theme, you have no 'home' page in pages. But now there is no navigation menu for home, only the logo can take to the home page, when clicking on it anywhere on the site.

But when I create a page called 'home' to add it to my menu, it links to the following link

```
http://myurl/home/ ‎
```

and I cannot change the permalink to:

```
http://myurl/
```

So how do I add a home page menu that actually links to the home page

PS - I do not want to use jquery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a custom menu and include a "custom links" item that's named "home" and links to the site URL.

Comment: Custom menus were introduced in 3.0; if you learned WP before that, you might have overlooked them until now.